Drupal 10 - How to Pass Arguments to Page
In Drupal 7 I used panels and page manager to create a URL and pass arguments to custom pages. A route might look something like /custom_section/!1/!2.
I need to do something similar in Drupal 10. I have been creating pages by adding basic pages and using layout builder to add blocks. I can add contextual filters to views blocks and get them to work in the views preview. I just can figure out how to pass the arguments to the views blocks in the page.
What is the best way to create custom pages in Drupal 10 that pass arguments to views or views blocks?

The simplest method is to create a route inside a custom module. A section of the route will be your parameter that you will pass to the view.
This is your .routing.yml file:
// custom_module/custom_module.routing.yml
custom_module.dynamic_page:
  path: '/custom-page/{argument}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\CustomPageController::content'
    _title: 'Custom Dynamic Page'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

And this is part of your controller file:
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\views\Views;

/**
 * Controller for custom pages with view arguments.
 */
class CustomPageController extends ControllerBase {

  ....

  /**
   * Displays the page content with a view that accepts arguments.
   *
   * @param string $argument
   *   The argument to pass to the view.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A render array representing the page content.
   */
  public function content($argument) {
    // Method 1: Embed a view with arguments
    $view = Views::getView('your_view_name');
    if (is_object($view)) {
      $view->setDisplay('block_1');
      $view->setArguments([$argument]);
      $view->execute();
      
      $content['view'] = $view->buildRenderable('block_1', [$argument]);
    }
    ....
 }
}


Thank you for the detailed response, ZioBudda. I thought it would likely require a custom module in D10
